# PHP If statement rerun

Tags: php

I've just caught a bug in my PHP programming and i can figure out why, in my MVC controller, i have an if statement, however, when the controller is passed, it goes through both statements...

```
public function actionCheckin($id) {
        $model = $this->loadScanningModel($id);


        if($model->checkin_status_id == 0){
            //checkin user
            $model->checkin_status_id = 1;                

            $model->save();
            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id, 'scanning' =>'success'));
        }
        else{
            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id, 'scanning' =>'reg'));
        }
    }
```

What this will do is if the checkin_status_id = 0 it will run the first condition, but instead of ending the code with the redirect, it will run the else query and the condition has now been met with the if, and go to the other redirect...

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this function is only getting called once?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like something at the first redirect target may be calling it a second time.

Comment: Or save() calls actionCheckin() a second time.

Comment: Various possibilities. But nothing visible in this code would be doing that. It's just an if/else. It has to be something external to this function.

Comment: Thanks guys, I don't believe the controllers being called more than once, but could be as you say, it's being called by save() or redirect somehow. To clarify, I'm using Yii php framework, if that makes any difference

Comment: Use xdebug and set break point on first line of function, if possible. It would be easy to catch the bug then.